# Parse Application Returning Incorrect Geolocation

Tags: objective-c, geolocation, parse-platform

I am currently building a GPS application with xcode and parse. The application appears to be working fine except the latitude and longitude coordinates returned are incorrect. What's strange is that it consistently returns 37.785834,-122.406417 which is Powell Station in San Francisco, a place that I've been before with my computer. Not sure if this is just a coincidence. Has anyone else encountered this sort of problem? How did you solve it? Thank you for your time.

I am using the standard Parse methods described in the parse documentation.

```
- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
// Create the location manager if this object does not
// already have one.
    if (nil == _locationManager)
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

// Set a movement threshold for new events.
_locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.1; // meters

[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)startSignificantChangeUpdates
{
// Create the location manager if this object does not
// already have one.
if (nil == _locationManager)
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    CLLocation *location = self.locationManager.location;

// Configure the new event with information from the location.

///*************************************************************//

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

   geoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
```

Comment: You are not providing any useful information (such as relevant code).

Comment: Simulator, or a device?